# Java script returning undefined when triggered

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

this is the function, and below designer code. I have updated the code with the latest answer

```
   function OnClientLoBChecked(sender, args) {

    var ChkBoxLOB = document.getElementById("<%= cbFLoB.ClientID %>");
    var ChkBoxDis = document.getElementById("<%= chkBoxShowNewProjects.ClientID %>");  
    if (ChkBoxLOB.Checked) {

        ChkBoxDis.checked = false}
    else{
        ChkBoxDis.checked = true

    }
    filterChanged();
    } 

    <telerik:radcombobox id="cbFLob" runat="server" datatextfield="LobName" checkboxes="true" OnClientItemChecked="OnClientItemChecked">
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors in this function.  `Function` needs to be `function`, `True` needs to be `true`... What is output on the console when you run this?

Comment: There is no return statement. Which variable should be returned?

Comment: I am checking a condition in the function, and performing a operation not returning any values. i am getting chkBocLob.checked as undefined.

Comment: What is the intention of the function?

Comment: `var ChkBoxLob = $find("<%= cbFLob.clientID%>");` is probably returning undefined, then you are tryng to check its value

Comment: document.getelementByID("<%= chBoxNewProjects.clientID%>") , may be this line

Comment: @Yannam I edited my answer because I realized you're not actually using jQuery. Take a look and try it out; it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the incorrectly capitalized `document.getElementById()` in your code, the real issue is that `ChkBoxLob` will always be undefined.

> You are using [$find](https://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/FindShortcutMethod.aspx) which is an `ASP.net` function that finds components registered with the `addComponent` method.

These components are `.net AJAX server controls` that have a JavaScript counterpart. The `$find()` method is not meant to be used like the JavaScript `document.getElementById()` or the jQuery `$('#someId)` notation.

That is why `chkBoxLob` is always undefined;

Use `document.getElementById` instead in both places.

```
var ChkBoxLob = document.getElementById("<%= cbFLob.ClientID %>");
var ChkBoxDis = document.getElementById("<%= chBoxNewProjects.ClientID %>");
```

Note also the capitalized `.ClientID` property.

Comment: I have tried using the updated code, when I check for  ChkBoxLob.Checked its always Undefined

Comment: Make sure your capitalization is correct on all of the JavaScript method names and also the ASP.net properties.

Comment: I updated the Question with the latest code, can you please take a look

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error? Use the developer tools console in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to see if there's an error. It's hard to tell from your updated code where the issue might be.